# how to store array values into array list and also need to print the reverse of resultant array list

Tags: java, arrays

I have tried below code i am getting array index out of bound exception. can any one help me out here.

```
public class RevSortedArry {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr1[]={45,63,82,13,5,907,342,654,-776,-123};

        Arrays.sort(arr1);

        System.out.print("Sorted Array is :: ");
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0){
                System.out.print(", ");
             }
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);


        }

        int arr2[]=new int[arr1.length];

        System.arraycopy(arr1,0,arr2,0,arr1.length);


            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr2));

            Collections.reverse(arrayList);

            System.out.println(arrayList);
    }

}
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr2)` is going to be problematic, as `Arrays.asList` expects an array of objects, not primitives (like `int`)

Comment: Use a for loop to reverse print the array instead of using Collections.reverse

Comment: Are you sure you encountered an exception . I compiled and run your code . There is no exception encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps check your code again, I've compiled and ran below code without any issues,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr1[]={45,63,82,13,5,907,342,654,-776,-123};

        Arrays.sort(arr1);

        System.out.print("Sorted Array is :: ");
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0){
                System.out.print(", ");
             }
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);


        }

        int arr2[]=new int[arr1.length];

        System.arraycopy(arr1,0,arr2,0,arr1.length);


            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr2));

            Collections.reverse(arrayList);

            System.out.println(arrayList);
    }

}
```

Comment: Check console, that gibberish string in the end of the line is supposed to be reverse sort.

Comment: However OP's question is about an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

Try this - check out the 2nd for loop and its conditions:

```
    public class Sort
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int arr1[]={45,63,82,13,5,907,342,654,-776,-123};

        Arrays.sort(arr1);

        System.out.print("Sorted Array is : ");
        for(int i=0; i<arr1.length; i++)
        {
            if(i != 0){
                System.out.print(", ");
             }
            System.out.print(arr1[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

        int arr2[]=new int[arr1.length];

        System.arraycopy(arr1,0,arr2,0,arr1.length);

        ArrayList<Integer> arr2List = new ArrayList<>();
            System.out.print("Reverse: ");
            for (int i = arr2.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
                //adding into list
                arr2List.add(arr2[i]);
                //printvalue
                System.out.print(arr2[i]+" ");
            }
    }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.Arrays;  
import java.util.Collections;  

public class RevSortedArry {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int arr1[]={45,63,82,13,5,907,342,654,-776,-123};  
        System.out.println("Before Sorting : " + Arrays.toString(arr1));  

        Arrays.sort(arr1);  
        System.out.print("Sorted Array is :: " );  
        for(int i=0; i<(arr1.length); i++)  
        {  
            System.out.print((arr1[i]) + "\t");  
        }  

        int arr2[]=new int[arr1.length];  

        //Copying arr1 into arr2  
        System.arraycopy(arr1,0,arr2,0,arr1.length);  

        //newArray for storing arr2 as Integer  
        Integer[] newArray = new Integer[arr2.length];  
        int i = 0;  
        for (int value : arr2) {  
            newArray[i++] = Integer.valueOf(value);  
        }  

        //creating arrayList of type integer  
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList =   
        new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(newArray));  
        System.out.println("\nArray List is :" + arrayList);  

        Collections.reverse(arrayList);  
        System.out.println(arrayList);  
    }
}
```

Change is i have converted int array arr2 to Integer array newArray may be thats causing you problem but i didn't got any exception with your code also. Please try it out.